# CSS flex-grow value not responding to click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexbox

I made a simple unit converter that converts pixel values to relative ratio values, then takes those ratio numbers and sets them as values for the 'flex-grow' property of a series of boxes (in the top right corner of the screenshot).

Here's a screenshot.

[image: calc screenshot]

Now, here's what I've got.

JS:

```
$('.calc-btn').click(function(){
    var inputs = [];
    $('.input-box input').each(function(){
        var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
        inputs.push(num);  
    });

    var minValue = Math.min.apply(Math,inputs); // get minimum value in array

    //calculation part
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i] = (inputs[i] / minValue);
        inputs[i] = parseFloat(inputs[i].toFixed(2));
    }

    $('span.input-response').each(function(i){
        $(this).text(inputs[i]);
    });

    //here's where I'm running into trouble
    $('.demo-tile').each(function(i){
        $(this).css('flex-grow',inputs[i]);
    });

    $('.flex-grow-value').each(function(i){
        $(this).text(inputs[i]);
    });
});
```

The problem is, every single command in the click event executes properly except for the one that changes $('.demo-tile')'s flex-grow value to inputs[i]. What makes it even weirder is that I can put a number value, say '10', in instead of inputs[i] and it will work. I also was able to set the text value of each box successfully using inputs[i]. I just can't seem to get the flex-grow property to accept inputs[i] as a value.

Comment: Which browsers have you tested?

Comment: just working in chrome. i haven't really tested anywhere else. But the flex-grow property is working elsewhere on the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

I needed to convert the value to a string, for .css() to accept it.

final javascript:

```
$('.demo-tile').each(function(i){

        $(this).css('flex-grow',inputs[i].toString());

});
```